# Error with List<T>, says "Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' requires 1 type arguments"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Working on the shopping part of thisnd smeting strange is happening. When I go to populate my lixt I get the error:

> Using the generic type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   requires 1 type arguments

I have done this on several other classes but none give this error. Here's the class causing the error:

**StoreItem.cs**

```
public class StoreItemViewModel
{
    public StoreItemViewModel()
    {
        this.StoreItems = GetStoreItemList(null);
    }

    private SelectList GetStoreItemList(string selectedValue)
    {
        List<StoreItems> list = new List<StoreItems>(); 
        IRepository<GodsCreationTaxidermy.Data.StoreItem> storeItems = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<StoreItem>>();

        foreach (StoreItem item in storeItems.GetAll())
        {
            List.Add(new StoreItems <= error on this line
            {
                Key = item.Key,
                CategoryKey = item.CategoryKey,
                ItemName = item.ItemName,
                ItemDescription = item.ItemDescription,
                ItemPriced = item.ItemPrice,
                DatePosted = item.DatePosted,
            });
        }

        return new SelectList(list, "StoreItemID", "StoreItemName", selectedValue);
    }

    [UIHint("StoreItems")]
    public SelectList StoreItems { get; private set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Store Item is required")]
    public string StoreItem { get; set; }
}
```

I can show other classes that do this exact thing (maybe a new set f eyes can here) and here's one of them:

**AnimalList.cs**

```
public class AnimalsList
{
    public AnimalsList()
    {
        this.Animals = GetanimalList(null); 
    }

    private SelectList GetanimalList(string selectedValue)
    {

        List<Animal> list = new List<Animal>();
        IRepository<AnimalList> animals = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<AnimalList>>();

        foreach (AnimalList animal in animals.GetAll())
        {
            list.Add(new Animal
            {
                AnimalId = animal.animal_id,
                AnimalName = animal.animal_name,
                IsBird = Convert.ToBoolean(animal.is_bird),
                MountType = animal.mount_type
            });
        }

        return new SelectList(list, "AnimalId", "AnimalName", selectedValue);
    }

    [UIHint("Animal")]
    public SelectList Animals { get; private set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Animal is required")]
    public string Animal { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone tell me wat I'm doing wrong here. I've seen a lot of very obscure errors the past few days (most I resolved) but others I had to ask for help.If you nee more code then ust let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List is capitalized, so you're referencing the Class instead of the instance "list".

You should consider changing the variable name to something useful, and less vague or error prone so you can catch these faster, or prevent them entirely.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you see *List.Add*, that's not going to work. Once I made it lower case all is well.